# How to get a Room Database ViewModel instance inside WorkManager?

Tags: android-room, android-viewmodel, android-workmanager

I am newbie in Android development. I am failing to get the **room db viewmodel which extends AndroidViewModel inside WorkManager**. I want to get a viewmodel class instance to do insert inside room db.

***AppAdViewModel.class***

```
public class AppAdViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AppAdRepository appAdRepository;

    public AppAdViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        appAdRepository = new AppAdRepository(application);
    }

    public void insert(AppAdModel appAdModel){
        appAdRepository.insertAd(appAdModel);
    }

}
```

***MyBackgroundWorker.class***

```
public class AppDataSyncingworker extends Worker{


    private Context context;
    private AppAdViewModel appAdViewModel;

    public AppDataSyncingworker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams){
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        this.context = getApplicationContext();
        // error on this line
        this.appAdViewModel = new ViewModelProvider((AppCompatActivity)context).get(AppAdViewModel.class);
        return null;
    }
```

The error it's showing is:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:298)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Any help or guide what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Calling getApplicationContext() should not be the preferred way of getting the Context. public constructor of Worker takes a Context as the first parameter. You can use that

Comment: yeah i tried with that. this.context = context. And yet, it didn't work out, mate!